# Wordpress metabox order data location

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, drag-and-drop, meta-boxes

Wordpress makes it possible to drag & drop metaboxes. 
Where does wordpress save the data in which order the meta boxes must be rendered?

I know it fires a AJAX request to `admin-ajax.php` the moment you drop a metabox but I haven't got any further than that.

I could not find any documentation on it regarding the alteration or the functionality of the Javascript's Wordpress uses to do this.

I need to be able to retrieve the order of meta boxes per post.
Each post can have it's own order of metaboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Take look into `wp_usermeta` and filter `meta_key` by `meta-box-order%`

```
SQL Query:
SELECT * FROM `wp_usermeta` WHERE `meta_key` LIKE 'meta-box-order%'
```

Comment: I have, This is the result

Array
(
    [acf_after_title] => 
    [side] => submitdiv,postimagediv,site_content_box,site_delete_box
    [normal] => 738,739,slugdiv
    [advanced] => 
)

But this seems like the data for one post.

Comment: I've tested this. moving one box, change order on all other pages. It works for only one user. Each user can have their settings.

Comment: hmmm, any tips on doing it just for one single post?

Comment: yes, it is possible.you can hook `get_user_option` using `add_filter`. Edit your question, and add info about setting order on only one post. I will edit my answer and add code how to do this :)